# efficient shifting of multi-dimensional arrays in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran

I have several 4-dimensional arrays each having different sizes:

```
array_one(1:2,1:xm,1:ym,1:zm)
```

where `current_step = 1` and `previous_step = 2`.

In a long loop, with many other operations, I need to shift the current_step values to the previous_step like:

```
array_one(previous_step,:,:,:) = array_one(current_step,:,:,:)
```

I know I can do that in a DO loop but, perhaps it is not the most efficient way. Since I have at least 24 such arrays each having different sizes (i.e. xm,ym,zm) so I need to run separate DO loops for each of them which could make it slower.

I failed with the following way:

```
array_one(previous_step,:,:,:) = array_one(current_step,:,:,:)
```

What is the efficient way for such shifting?

Comment: I think the most efficient way to do what you probably are trying to do, rather than to do what you are asking to be helped to do, is to use `current` and `previous` as indices to `1` and `2` and to swap those values at the end of each step.  No data movement at all.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark's suggestion is optimal.  Any copy you do is going to be time dependent on the size of your arrays, while the suggested method will be constant time independent of your array sizes and avoid copying altogether.

Comment: If you really do need to do such copy operations it would *likely* be better to make the step index the *last* array index instead of the first, so that you would be copying a contiguous block of data. (for fortran that is )

Answer (score 3):

#### Copy methods

I ran a simple benchmark on my system with 8 different methods to copy the arrays.  There were two basic forms of copy I tested:

```
do k=1,nx
do j=1,nx
do i=1,nx
   array(2,i,j,k) = array(1,i,j,k)
end do
end do
end do
```

and

```
array(2,:,:,:) = array(1,:,:,:)
```

For each of these I also tested with the `t` index as the last array index, e.g.:

```
array(i,j,k,2) = array(i,j,k,1)
```

and

```
array(:,:,:,2) = array(:,:,:,1)
```

Finally I tested each of these 4 copies as shown serially and with openmp directives, e.g.

```
!$omp parallel do shared(array) private(i,j,k)
...
!$omp end parallel do
```

for the `do` loop copy and with

```
!$omp parallel workshare shared(array)
...
!$omp end parallel workshare
```

for the array slice copy.

Each copy was performed 100 times for each of arrays sized 100x100x100x2 up to 1000x1000x1000x2 in increments of 100 (ni=nj=nk for all tested arrays).

#### The compiler and compile flags

I tested with gfortran 4.9.1, and compiled my testcase with

```
gfortran -march=native -fopenmp -O3 -o arraycopy arraycopy.f90
```

My CPU is an intel i7 990x (6 cores with HT enabled), and `native` will target the highest instruction set supported by the chip.  OpenMP will spawn 12 threads.

The OS is Linux 3.12.13.

#### Results

[image: Copy results]

Average time per copy is on the y-axis and the array dimension is on the x-axis (e.g. 500 is a 500x500x500x2 or 2x500x500x500 array).  The red lines are the do loop copy (dashed is the variation with `t` index last).  The green lines are the array slice copy (dashed is the variation with `t` index last).  For both serial copies the variations with `t` index first were faster (I did not investigate why) and the array notation copy is faster than the loop.  The blue lines are the openmp copies with `t` index first.  The black lines are the openmp copies with the `t` index last.  The performance for the parallel do and parallel workshare constructs were equivalent.

#### Discussion

Run your own benchmarks on your own systems with your typical compile flags.  The results here are going to be specific to my system including optimization flags, SIMD instructions and OpenMP with 12 threads.  This *will* vary for a system with fewer cores and a CPUs with lesser or greater instruction sets (e.g. a CPU with AVX2 should perform better).  These results are also influenced by cache locality, RAM and bus speeds and how my OS scheduler handles hyperthreading.

For my results on my system I would use array slice notation for serial copies and for best performance I would use OpenMP.

Comment: Nice test relevant also for a wider audience.

Answer (score 1):

In short, when a program issues a memory read operation, say `A(i)`, it will not only read `A(i)`, but instead it will read something like `A(i-2), A(i-1), A(i), A(i+1), A(i+2)`. These values will then be stored in the CPU cache, which is a much faster memory. That is, the CPU will read a chunk of memory and put it into cache for later use. This optimization is based on the fact that it is very likely that your next operation will use some of these surrounding values. If that's the case, the CPU won't need to go and fetch the memory again, which is a very expensive operation (like 100 times more expensive than floating point operations), instead it just needs to look for the value in the cache. This is called *data locality*.

In Fortran, multidimensional arrays are stored in *column-major order*. For instance, let's say you have the following 2x2 matrix:

`A(1,1)=a11, A(1,2)=a12, A(2,1)=a21, A(2,2)=a22`.

The matrix `A(1:2,1:2)` is stored linearly in memory in this order: `a11, a21, a12, a22` (in contrast, in a *row-major order* like C language, the order would be `a11, a12, a21, a22`). You can deduce what the order is for higher dimensions.

In short, Fortran arrays are stored linearly in memory from *left to right*. If you want to exploit data locality, you need to travel through the array from *left to right*.

**Short answer:** I think you should change your structure to `(1:xm,1:ym,1:zm,1:2)`, and if you are going to loop through the array, do it this way:

```
do h = 1, 2
  do i = 1, zm
    do j = 1, ym
      do k = 1, xm
        A[k,j,i,h] = *...something...*
      end do
    end do
  end do
end do
```

Also, the difference between doing `A(:)=B(:)` and the equivalent do loop is that `A(:)=B(:)` is equivalent to a `forall` statement:

```
forall(i = 1:n)
  A(i) = B(i)
end forall
```

More in here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran_95_language_features#The_FORALL_Statement_and_Construct

Comment: "Also, the difference between doing A(:)=B(:) and the equivalent do loop is that A(:)=B(:) is translated to a forall statement:"  Not really. And normal programmer just writes `A=B`.

Comment: I'm just stating what is written in Wikipedia, but again, Wikipedia may be wrong. In which ways do you say they differ? And I personally like to write explicitly `(:)` to let it be clear that it's an array. But it's a personal preference.

Comment: That wiki article is very good. It is written by M.Metcalf. But you are interpreting it wrong. It doesn't state anything about translating. It actually is about what `forall` is and that it is equivalent to a series of array assignments.